# Extraneous Package when Installed Locally

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I was trying to install *phantomjs* in order to `make test` [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). After I had installed it locally i.e. `npm install phantomjs`, it reported that the package was extraneous.

```
├─┬ phantomjs@1.9.0-3 extraneous
│ ├── adm-zip@0.2.1
...
npm ERR! extraneous: phantomjs@1.9.0-3 /Users/admin/bootstrap/node_modules/phantomjs
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

However, when *phantomjs* was installed globally i.e. `npm install phantomjs -g`, it worked fine i.e. no extraneous error reported.

Questions:

1. Is it because *phantomjs* [not specified in the *package.json* file](http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/10/17/npm-features-and-options-demystified/)?
2. General question: Can we have any package e.g. *phantomjs* installed globally and also locally?

Comment: `extraneous: not forming a necessary part of something...` is it just me or is it strange that packages you *need* are "extraneous?"

Answer (score 80):

1. Yes. (Re-installing with `npm install` wont install phantom.js again.) (Btw.: `npm install xxx --save` will automatically add xxx to the package.json)
2. Yes. Local package versions are preferred over global ones. (Although you need some path handling for executables.)

Comment: use -save-dev to save this as a developer dependency

Comment: @VincentDeSmet should be `--save-dev` or `-D` as a shorthand, you missed a dash at the beginning.

Comment: why are local preferred over global

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd because you could have different versions of the same package depending on the project you are working on.

Answer (score 10):

1. phantomjs should be included in your local .json package(manually editing it or using --save command see TheHippo's answer). If it is installed somewhere and you don't need it use the prune command

   `npm prune`

will remove all non-required packages.

2. To install an item both locally and globally use:

   `sudo npm install -g phantomjs`