# npm path and installation issues - suggestions

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have used to install my nodejs on D:\ drive instead of C and have set environment variables to D drive node & npm folders.

Then i changed npm installation path as "prefix=D:\node\node_modules\npm
" on "npmrc" file. So i could confirm that all user based modules are pointing on D drive npm folder instead of appdata.

I tried to install express js globally and i used to check the package tree on my cli as mentioned below,
npm ll -g

while trying this command am getting npm extraneous ERR,

[image]

Please suggest me that which way i have to use npm path and installation stuffs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extraneous Package when Installed Locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252750/extraneous-package-when-installed-locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem like a good idea to install packages globally, but this is one great reason not to.

Often used packages like `express`, and `cookies` should be kept local to a package. Mostly because of versioning issues. You might have one package using `express2`, but your new one wants to use `express3`. You would have trouble if it was a global install. When in doubt leave off that `-g`, and use a `--save` instead. (This adds the package to your `npm` dependencies list.)

On the other hand, command line tools like `mocha`, `yeoman`, and uh not much else that I know of should be installed with the `-g` flag.

I'm not much of a windows person, so you'll have to look a little yourself, but I would also recommend *not* installing Node by hand, but instead using a *version manager* like `nvm` to do that stuff. Here's an `nvm` port for windows: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: Hi Breedly. I got some idea about the version related issues. Thanks for your valuable time.